# Selenium IEDriver / Firefox Driver browser location Error

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

unexpectedly I am experiencing this issue. I am trying to run my testcase. For Firefox or IE browser but I don't know where is the issue. It cannot find the browser location.

```
Selenium.WebDriver -Version 2.52.0
Selenium.Support -Version 2.52.0
Selenium.RC -Version 2.52.0
Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium -Version 2.52.0
```

It was working perfectly but soon after I updated my nupackages. I am having this issue. Also I tried to use previous version but now I am having same problem in that one as well.

Error:

IEDriver

[image: IEDriver Error]

FirefoxDriver Error

[image: FirefoxDriver Error]

Enviorment Variable

Installed Location:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
```

Comment: what exact error you got?

Comment: @Andersson Please Check I have uploaded my screenshot

Comment: For `IE` issue you need to download `IEdriverServer.exe` from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ and place it to the folder that exists in your system PATH. Second means that `Firefox` browser is not installed. Even if it actually installed, try to reinstall it

Comment: @Andersson I did reinstalled as well using `44.0.2`

Comment: can you print out your environment variables and also the path of the ie driver and firefox install location??

Comment: @JyothishwarDeo Added in my description

Comment: @user7107, default location for `firefox.exe` should be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox`. make sure that executive file present there or add actual path to file to system PATH

Comment: Also I have IE under Program Files x86 but it is not recognizing it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're mentioning path of IEDriverServer executable in PATH variable of your system.

echo $PATH

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well. I tried to download older version from the below link and it worked. Let me know, if that helped. About IE I am trying to figure it out what should be the case.

[Firefox version download](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/)

You don't need to alter your code. Also Anderson is right you probably might have downloaded x64 version and I think Selenium might be trying to find x86 version (in Program File) which might have caused the problem.

Comment: It did helped. And yes it was x86 file location but by default IE location is same but why it is not recognising?

Comment: You just need to add [IEDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) which according to me is missing.

Answer (score 0):

For IE Driver download it (32bit) [LINK](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

After that your browser init need to be something like that:

```
InternetExplorerDriverService driverService = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
driverService.LibraryExtractionPath = @"c:\drivers\"; // here is your driver location

InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.EnableNativeEvents = true;
options.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(driverService, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

For Firefox just try to update the firefox to last version.